# Entity Framework search for recipes with an array of ingredients

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, search

I have a search which returns all recipes where at least one ingredient matches the search string

```
recipes = db.Recipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients.Any(i => i.IngredientName.Contains(searchString)));
```

The user inputs the search string in the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ <p> Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p> }
```

But what if I the search string needs to be multiple ingredients at a time.

I have tried splitting the string into an array. Making and SQL join to get a list of recipes and the ingredients they contain. But I don't know what to do from there.

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string[] FilteredsearchString, string searchString)
        {
            FilteredsearchString = searchString.Split(default(string[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            // "string" can be lowercase.
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", FilteredsearchString));

            // ... "String" can be uppercase.
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", FilteredsearchString));

            IQueryable recipes;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                recipes = db.Recipes;
            }
            else
            {
                var Allrecipes = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
                         "SELECT * FROM Recipes" +
                         "INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient ON Recipes.RecipeID = RecipeIngredient.RecipeRefID " +
                         "INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient.IngredientRefID = Ingredients.IngredientID " +
                         "WHERE Ingredients.IngredientName IN ()").ToList();

                recipes = from r in Allrecipes where FilteredsearchString.Contains("Ingredient.IngredientName");
            }
            return View(recipes);
        }
```

Comment: `But what if I the search string needs to be multiple ingredients at a time.` Let's say you chose 15 ingredients. Does a recipe need to use 1 of those ingredients? 15? 1 or more? Something else?

Comment: The recipe needs to have one of those ingredients and the user needs to specify one or more

Comment: `recipes = db.Recipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients.Any(i => 
yourListContainingIngredientsTheySelected.Contains(i.IngredientName));` Does this do what you need?

Comment: It actually does return the desired result! Thank you good sir.

Answer (score -1):

I would probably just do it in a loop and join them together.

```
        string[] searchStrings = new string[0]; // Your array of search terms.
        List<Recipe> recipes = new List<Recipe>(); // A list to store the results.
        for (int i = 0; i < searchStrings.Length; i++) // Loop through all the search keywords
        {
            recipes.AddRange(db.Recipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients.Any(i => i.IngredientName.Contains(searchStrings[i])))); // Add all recipes that match.
        }
```

You will of course have to make sure to not have any duplicate results yourself. :)

Comment: If `searchStrings.Length` is 15, how many SQL statements will be executed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Entity Framework concatenates the statements into as few as possible, but I may be mistaken.
You can always print out the resulting query to see for yourself.

Comment: It will run 15 queries

Comment: Yeah. I see that now, looking back. XD